# boolean always false after 32 seconds

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide

I have a boolean expression (I think it's called), and it will always return false after 32 seconds of running, and I'm very confused now.

```
if (millis() > stepTime+lightCmd[stepe][5]) {
  stepe = (stepe+1)%STEPS; //I'm bad at naming variables, sorry
  stepTime = millis();
  Serial.println("changing"); // debugging
}
```

This runs inside the main loop.

Also, I've tried using an exponent when trying to get some lights to appear to fade linearly and in about the same amount of time, 32 seconds, it would start fading in reverse.

EDIT:

millis(); wouldn't go backwards after it stopped working

Comment: Use the https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay example. You should not compare millis to a value and you should not add something to the millis value. If you have a problem, please provide a full working sketch, so we can test it.

Comment: @Jot please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Is stepTime an `unsigned long` ?

Comment: no, it's an integer, it's the same as previousMilliseconds in the blink without delay, link on first comment

Comment: @Jot I tried doing something similar to the example, but it seems to be returning true once it gets to 32 seconds, I'm going to look more carefully at the example

Comment: You code is nothing like the blink without delay. There is a specific way to use millis: **"the current millis" - "a previous millis value" >= interval**. And the current millis and the previous millis **must** be a "unsigned long". The current millis can also be a call to millis() of course. An integer? And the 32 seconds is perhaps 32767 milliseconds?

Comment: @Jot ok, I was going to try making stepTime an unsigned long just now, so thanks!

Comment: When you add a value to 'stepTime' and still use the '>' with millis, then you still have the rollover problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just note that `millis` will overflow after about 50 days. So if you project has to run longer that that, the if-statement will fail after 50 days.

Comment: @Gerben I won't need to run it nearly that long, so it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with `millis` and `micros` you must always use `unsigned long` variables; otherwise, values will be overflow/truncate.

When doing time arithmetic, you must always use differences, not additions, because of the nature of unsigned arithmetic.

Your updated sketch is this:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);    
    while(!Serial);    
    Serial.println(); Serial.println("Test");
}

#define STEPS 3
unsigned long lightCmd[STEPS] = {4000, 60000, 90000};
int stepe = 0;
unsigned long stepTime = 0;

void loop()
{
    if(millis() - stepTime >= lightCmd[stepe]) {
        Serial.print(stepe);
        Serial.print(".- ");
        stepe = (stepe+1)%STEPS; //I'm bad at naming variables, sorry
        stepTime = millis();
        Serial.print(stepTime);
        Serial.println(" changing"); // debugging
    }
}
```